# Error on Fragment screen orientation update

Tags: android, android-fragments, screen-orientation

When I press a button from fragment A the fragment B is shown. The problem occurs when I change the the screen orientation; instead of the view of fragment B being updated, the fragment A appears updated; if I want to see the fragment B updated I need to press the same button again.
What is recommended on fragments calling another fragment? What do I have to do to prevent this inappropriate update of fragment A?

Comment: you need to force the orientation not to change or take care of the event resulting in orientation change. by saving and restoring the state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On orientation change your activity is being recreated.

Add following property to activity in manifest file:

```
android:configChanges = "orientation|screenSize"
```

This will prevent recreation of activity on screen update.